# MySQL SELECT Name of Stored Procedure and CALL it by that name

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, call

There is a table `bar` that stores procedures names:

```
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 | one  |
|  2 | two  |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and a table `foo` that stores data that procedures should operate on:

```
+----+-------+
| id | data  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | three |
|  2 | four  |
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

procedure `one` looks this way:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `one`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `one`()
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('Proc one: ', `data`) AS `Result`
    FROM `foo`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and calling it this way:

```
CALL one();
```

gives desired result:

```
+-----------------+
| Result          |
+-----------------+
| Proc one: three |
| Proc one: four  |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

procedure `two` is identical to `one`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `two`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `two`()
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('Proc two: ', `data`) AS `Result` 
    FROM `foo` ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

calling `two` works also well:

```
CALL two();
```

result:

```
+-----------------+
| Result          |
+-----------------+
| Proc two: three |
| Proc two: four  |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**How to call `one` and `two` procedures not by using their names literally:**

```
call one();
call two();
```

**but using for that names stored in `bar` table?**

I tired using SELECT statement in place of their names but that did not work.

The wanted result is every procedure with the name in `bar` called with every row in `foo`:

```
+-----------------+
| Result          |
+-----------------+
| Proc one: three |
| Proc one: four  |
| Proc two: three |
| Proc two: four  |
+-----------------+
```

To replicate tables and procedures use this queries:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bar`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `foo`;

CREATE TABLE `bar`
(
    `id` SERIAL,
    `data` TEXT NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `bar` (`data`) VALUES
('one'),
('two')
;

CREATE TABLE `foo`
(
    `id` SERIAL,
    `data` TEXT NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `foo` (`data`) VALUES
('three'),
('four')
;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `one`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `one`()
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('Proc one: ', `data`) AS `Result`
    FROM `foo`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `two`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `two`()
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('Proc two: ', `data`) AS `Result` 
    FROM `foo` ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL one();
CALL two();
```

I'm using MySQL 8.